# Why does the level set equation $\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t} + v |\nabla \phi|=0$ become $\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t} = v |\nabla \phi|$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization

Why does the level set equation $$\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t} + v |\nabla \phi|=0$$ become $$\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t} = v |\nabla \phi|$$ rather than
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial t} = -v |\nabla \phi|$$

---

Source:

Compare

https://www.upct.es/goe/level-set-slides.pdf

to

http://physbam.stanford.edu/~fedkiw/papers/cam2000-08.pdf

---

Then again, i[n this presentation page 13](http://cau.ac.kr/~bongbong/vg12/vg06.ppt) there's:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=-F| \nabla \phi|$$

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: I would guess that the problems are equivalent, since if you have a solution to $\partial_{t} \phi + v | \nabla \phi | = 0$, then $\psi = - \phi$ is a solution to $\partial_{t} \psi - v | \nabla \psi | = 0$.

Comment: @Peter How are solutions of opposite signs equivalent? Wouldn't that mean that the solutions are moving to the opposite directions as well? Which in Level Set method ought not to be "equivalent"?

Comment: I am not familiar with the level set method. Suppose that $\phi$ obeys the equation $-\partial_t \phi = v | \nabla \phi |$. Then define $\psi=-\phi$. And compute $\partial_t \psi = - \partial_t \phi = v | \nabla \phi | = v | - \nabla \phi | = v | \nabla \phi |$. Thus *solving* the equation $\partial_{t} \phi + v | \nabla \phi | = 0$ is equivalent to solving the equation $\partial_{t} \psi - v | \nabla \psi | = 0$.